# How to get td value without class using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

The code which i am working on:

```html
 <table>
 
 <tr>
 <td>floor area</td>
 <td>60 m²</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>floor area unit</td>
 <td>30 m²</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>floor</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>rooms</td>
 <td>2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>bathroom</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>

 </table>
```

here's my code so far, to get floor area value

```html
var i = 0;
$('tr').each(function(){
    if (i==1){
        var floorarea= $(this).find('td')[2].text();
        dataparse.floorarea = floorarea;
            } i++;

        });
```

I'm newbie in Jquery, 
 1. and my questions is how can i able to get only this value 60 m² ? 
 2. how can i get all of td value ?
 do have any idea for me ?  please i need an advice.

Comment: What actual steps have you taken to solve your problem on your own means? Please see [ask].

Comment: try something out read the documents and when you are stuck on some thing comeback and ask for opinion

Comment: so as far, i trying with this code but still not working
var i = 0;
$('tr').each(function(){
    if (i==1){
        var floorarea= $(this).find('td')[2].text();
        dataparse.floorarea = floorarea;
            } i++;

        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/b1tyrpom/1/)

```
$("table tr").each(function(){
    var tdFirstval=$(this).find("td:first").html();
    var val=$(this).find("td:last").html(); 

    //floor area td value
    if(tdFirstval=="floor area"){           
      console.log("Floor Area TD Value: "+val);
    }   
    else
    {
      console.log((val);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked, one more question sir, do you have any idea how can i only get td value, just for "floor area" i want to get the 60 m².

Comment: You can check updated anwer. You need to check value of first td and compare it

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way also

```js
$('tr').each(function() {
var tdname = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
var tdvalue = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
  
if(tdname=="floor area"){
  alert(tdvalue);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 
 <tr>
 <td>floor area</td>
 <td>60 m²</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>floor area unit</td>
 <td>30 m²</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>floor</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>rooms</td>
 <td>2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>bathroom</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, really appreciated can i ask you a question sir, do you have any idea how can i only get td value, just for "floor area" i want to get the 60 m².